# Tests are passing in jenkins command prompt and failing in jenkins windows service

Tags: windows, selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

Can someone please help regarding the following :

Jenkins--Command Prompt:
Start Jenkins in cmd prompt 
Run the selenium framework 
Chrome opens in full screen and test cases are passed

Jenkins- Windows Services:
Start Jenkins as windows services
Run the selenium framework 
Chrome not opening in full screen and test cases are failed
#

I have installed latest chrome driver as well 
My Json config :

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [

    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
      "acceptSslCerts":true,
      "javascriptEnabled":true
    }
  ]
```

and :

```
        cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        cap.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
        cap.setCapability("jenkins.nodeName", "(master)");
```

But the above scenario doesn't work :
I have tried the following options also :

```
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
```

Note: I ran the framework as admin user too
it does fail.

Comment: Add this to your code `driver.manage().window().maximize();` and see if that fixes the issue

Comment: when tests fail what is the error that you're getting?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to run Chrome (without headless) in windows service. try using java agent for the node or headless chrome

Comment: @TarunLalwani :Window.maximize fails

Comment: @socalcheesehead : Am not not getting any specific error message .The issue is : Chrome doesn't open in full screen ..As its opening in minimized mode selenium unable to locate the elements .So test cases are failing